# Random Chord Creator with probabilities set that doesn't print the same note twice

Tags: python

Creating a Chord generator inspired by the Jazz music of SUN RA. I am attempting to create a chord generator that can be very customizable. So far I can feed it notes and give those notes set probabilities in my object 'note'. The problem I'm having is when it generates the sequence I'm sometimes getting the same note. Is there some way to maybe create an if statement between each print line to exclude whatever the random note that gets selected from the previous rendering so that the next note CANNOT be the same as the previous note?

I tried writing an if statement myself between each print line but it was very embarrassing, so I rather not share.

```html
import random
import numpy as np
class Note:

    def __init__(self, name, note):
        self.name = name
        self.gender= np.random.choice(["c", "e", "g", "b"],1,[0.5, .2, 0.1, 0.2])[0]



c = Note('c', 'yourNote')
d = Note('d', 'yourNote')
e = Note('e', 'yourNote')
f = Note('f', 'yourNote')
Your_Chord = Note(c.name, c.gender)
print(Your_Chord)
print(c.gender)
print(d.gender)
print(e.gender)
print(f.gender)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main thing you were missing out on was some way to track whatever was the most recent note and then make sure it is not selected.  I've added a class variable to track the last note, and a temp dict with it removed to pick from each time.  I hope this helps with your crazy jazz!

```
import numpy as np

# dict with the notes and weights
notes = {"c":0.5, "e":0.2, "g":0.1, "b":0.2}

class Note:
    _last_note = 'start'
    def __init__(self, name, note):
        self.name = name
        # here we temporarily create a dict without the last note in it
        new_notes = {k: notes[k] for k in set(list(notes.keys())) - set(Note._last_note)}
        self.gender = np.random.choice(list(new_notes.keys()-Note._last_note),1,list(new_notes.values()))[0]
        print("init ",self.gender,Note._last_note)
        Note._last_note = self.gender

    def print_chord(self):
        print("print chord ",self.name,self.gender)



c = Note('c', 'yourNote')
d = Note('d', 'yourNote')
e = Note('e', 'yourNote')
f = Note('f', 'yourNote')
Your_Chord = Note(c.name, c.gender)

Your_Chord.print_chord()

print(c.gender)
print(d.gender)
print(e.gender)
print(f.gender)

c.print_chord()
d.print_chord()
e.print_chord()
f.print_chord()
```